# Immutable table in Django

Tags: sql, django, model, readonly

I'm implementing the backend for a game. I have two set of table, game meta data tables which won't be changed during production, and user data tables. I'm thinking of optimization of the game meta data since they're totally immutable. some ideas come up to my mind are,

- use memory table engine in mysql [not sure how improvement can it gain]
- write a manager to cache all the results of queries to those table, provided there's no join between 2 types of table in SQL [still not very sure if possible]
- utilize cache out side model objects [though not so general]

what do you think is the best way to go? or other better way? thanks.

Comment: But would you still like to maintain/update/delete any of that data, e.g. via admin? If not, why do you not create simple Python objects instead of Django Models?

Comment: Writing manager is possible, but try cache middleware such as [johnny cache](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/johnny-cache) at first. Try other methods if the meta table  reading cost is still bottleneck..

Comment: @schacki I think admin is necessary and data would be imported by loaddata, so there would be a setting to switch on/off the cache.